# Using nunique to tag the duplicate values in a dataframe but getting an error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to tag unique value with a comment but I am getting TypeError: string indices must be integers

### Input

Key

ab

bc

df

ab

### Output

Key  | Comment

ab    |  Check it

bc     |

df      |

ab       |Check it

`condition_2= lambda x: "Check it" if x["Key"].nunique()>=1 else 0`
`df["Comments"]=semi_final_df.Key.apply(condition_2)`

Error:

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-175-dc8d1ac8148f> in <module>
----> 1 semi_final_df["Comments"]=semi_final_df.Key.apply(condition_2)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-174-cf54900ff760> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 condition_2= lambda x: " Check it" if x["Key"].nunique()>=1 else 0

TypeError: string indices must be integers```
````

Comment: I guess you missed the `axis` argument with apply. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for mask for all dupes with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["Comments"]= np.where(df.Key.duplicated(keep=False), "Check it", '')
print (df)
  Key  Comments
0  ab  Check it
1  bc          
2  df          
3  ab  Check it
```